# Edit contenteditable text with Ctrl-A (Select All) removing all child elements

Tags: html, contenteditable

In a div with contenteditable="true", if I select all text using Ctrl-A and then type something, it will removing all the child elements within the div, not just the text.

for example:

```
<div id="texteditor" contenteditable="true">
   CTRL-A and Edit Me.

   <div id="topleft-ornament" class="ornament"></div>
   <div id="topright-ornament" class="ornament"></div>
   <div id="bottomleft-ornament" class="ornament"></div>
   <div id="bottomright-ornament" class="ornament"></div>
</div>
```

the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/7jV4f/1/

the red circles (child elements of contenteditable div) in the example above will be removed if the text is edited using Ctrl-A.

any idea how to prevent it?

thx :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So wrap the text inside the div and assign `contenteditable` attribute to that particular element

```html
<div contenteditable="true">CTRL-A and Edit Me.</div>
<!-- Wrap the text, don't use contenteditable for the parent element -->
```

Answer (score 0):

For code tag you can set style "display: block":

`<pre style="display: block"></pre>`