# How to select all text inside code box without selecting all web page?

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS code that I use in my blogspot site to store all my code and technical snippets.

```
.code {
 background:#dae6ef;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 border: solid #5C7B90;
 border-width: 1px 1px 1px 20px;
 color: #000000;
 font: 13px 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
 line-height: 16px;
 margin: 10px 0 10px 10px;
 max-height: 200px;
 min-height: 16px;
 overflow-y: auto;
 padding: 10px 5px 5px;
 width: 90%;
}

 .code:hover {
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

If I go to my web page to select only all text inside the text box it will 
select all text in the whole page.

Not like this
[image]

I wanted it to be selecting only what's inside the code box when I hit CTRL + a.

I want this
[image]

Is that possible in CSS? BTW I have no CSS background, I just got that code from the web.

Comment: In a any other element then `input` and `textarea`, not without javascript.

Comment: have you tried `user-select: none;` ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select

Comment: @ShadowFoOrm, yeah I tried `user-select: none;` but it doesn't select any text on the code box.

Comment: don't tell me you added `user-select: none;` on the code box. you have to add it on other elements that you don't want the user to select it.

Answer (score 0):

Use input fields for your Text. by that pressing [CTRL] + [a] will only select the text inside the input. You can style input fields as you want so they can look like your text-

Answer (score 0):

its very simple , just assign `contenteditable="true"` in your html div and thats it

also check the similar question in [Edit contenteditable text with Ctrl-A (Select All) removing all child elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16542302/edit-contenteditable-text-with-ctrl-a-select-all-removing-all-child-elements)

Comment: this partially works however I don't want to make my code box editable.

Comment: no problem its still doable but can you please post the html code ?